# How to draw 3d surfaces in the form of $y=f(x)$ by pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I need to draw some 3D surfaces which have the form $y=f(x)$. Now the problem is that `pgfplots` take functions in the form $z=f(x,y)$ and here I deal with surfaces with free $z$ coordinate. For example, consider $y=\cos x$; my code is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    mesh/interior colormap name=black,
    colormap name=purple,
    xlabel=$x$,zlabel=$z$,ylabel=$y$] \addplot3  [samples=20,domain=.1:8,surf,
shader=faceted] {cos((x) r)};
\end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}
```

and this is wrong! Is it a way to draw such surfaces by `pgfplots`?

Comment: By default, when called with one argument, this argument determines the `z` value of the plot.

Comment: @marmot Thank you. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know how to interpret your question, but the fact that you say that `z` is free suggests

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{
    colormap={blackwhite}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}
}
 \pgfplotsset{
    colormap={cool}{rgb255(0cm)=(255,255,255); rgb255(1cm)=(0,128,255); rgb255(2cm)=(255,0,255)}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    mesh/interior colormap name=blackwhite,
    colormap name=cool,samples=180,
    xlabel=$x$,zlabel=$z$,ylabel=$y$] \addplot3  [samples=20,domain=.1:8,surf,
shader=faceted] ({x},{cos((x) r)},{y});
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]